# coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, FieldFile found

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views, django-forms

```py
# models.py


def document_file_name(instance, filename):

    char_set = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
    dat = "".join(random.sample(char_set * 6, 12))
    x = (
        str(instance.created_by_id)
        + "/"
        + dat
        + "_"
        + re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9-_.]", r"_", filename)
    )

    return (
        "documents/"
        + str(instance.created_by_id)
        + "/"
        + dat
        + "_"
        + re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9-_.]", r"_", filename)
    )


class UploadDocument(models.Model):

    document = models.FileField(upload_to=document_file_name, blank=True, null=True)
    other_doc = models.ForeignKey("doc.OtherDocuments")


# views.py


def opportunity_document_add(request, opportunity_id):

    c = setup_context(request)

    other_documents = get_object_or_404(OtherDocuments, pk=opportunity_id)

    c["other_documents "] = other_documents
    c["other_documents_id"] = other_documents
    document = UploadDocument(other_doc=other_documents)

    errors = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        document.type = request.POST.get("type")
        if "document" in request.FILES:

            document.document = request.FILES["document"].read()

            file = document.document

            bucket = settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
            s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
            object_name = None
            with open(file, "rb") as f:
                s3.upload_fileobj(f, bucket, file)

            document.save()
```

Here i am getting the error "coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, FieldFile found" and "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: "

Comment: You will need to also show the traceback, not just that you're getting an error.

Comment: Beside that, you should be (1) Using Python 3 (2) Using a custom Django Storage instead of managing S3 buckets by hand (3) Using Django forms instead of hand-managing `request.POST` (4) Use string formatting instead of concatenating with `+`, etc.